# PHP script gives output when run through command line but not through browser

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, command-line

When I run my program through command line, then my PHP script works fine and gives output properly.

But when I run it through my browser, then it processes fine but the output I printed - is not showing.

( Note : My script is running in a while loop and it will run forever )

Code - I am writing some part of my class file

```
public function call($n) {

    global $argv;
    $this->response = null;
    $this->corr_id = uniqid();

    $msgBody = 'test msg';

    //Create queue
    $this->createQueue($queueName);

    $msg = new AMQPMessage(
            (string) $msg_body,
            array('correlation_id' => $this->corr_id,
                  'reply_to' => $this->callback_queue,
                  'priority' => 2)
            );
    $this->channel->basic_publish($msg, '', $queueName);

    while(!$this->response) {
        $this->channel->wait();
    }

    return $this->response;

}

$response = call();
```

createQueue() function is in another class

```
function createQueue($queueName='')
{
    $exchange = 'router';
    $queue = 'msgs';
    $consumer_tag = 'consumer';

    $connection = new AMQPConnection(HOST, PORT, USER, PASS, VHOST);
    $channel = $connection->channel();

    $channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, false, false, false);

    echo " [x] Awaiting for message\n";
    $callback = function($req) {
    $n = $req->body;
    echo "$n\n";

    $msg = new AMQPMessage(
            'msg',
            array('correlation_id' => $req->get('correlation_id'))
            );

    $req->delivery_info['channel']->basic_publish(
            $msg, '', $req->get('reply_to'));
    $req->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack(
            $req->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    };

    $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $channel->basic_consume($queueName, '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {

        $channel->wait();

    }
}
```

Comment: And... You expect us to solve your problems based on that....? Please post code...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: Hey @conceptdeluxe - can you please your answer in answer section? so that I can accept your answer :) ..this works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can :)

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php - this is the way to go for permanently running scripts when you need to output before the response is complete.

Also have a look at the first user comment there - it is about sending in 4KB chunks with `str_pad()` as browsers tend to not display anything at all until a specific amount of data is reached.

Comment: Nice - If there is a will, there is a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

That is bound to happen when you have a script running in a while loop and run forever.

Running the script in browser will timeout and will not output stuff since the script is not completed.

while you run a script on Command Line, the script will be executed line by line and output will be shown

Comment: Then what's the solution? :)

Comment: To test it in a browser, do not run while loop forever. The default timeout set in php is 30 seconds. You might want to change it or you can have lesser loops completed in 30 seconds

Comment: Actually I will run it using curl and I want it to run forever as the script will get parameters and it will gives output accordingly - just like pinging mechanism.

Comment: then the best way is to set up a batch script if you are on windows and curl if you are on linux and schedule the job, not just make it run forever

Comment: curl script is also not working - as it acts like a browser ofcourse

Comment: what does `$this->channel->wait();` do?

Comment: It is waiting for trigger

Comment: Just return the waiting. Dont wait. You have to run the commands in batches scheduling it

Answer (score 1):

Why does the loop need to run forever and ever? If it never finishes, it will never actually return a response to the client.

As the php runs, it builds an HTML document in a buffer as you add to it, and then all at once it sends the page.

If the loop generates content for the page on every iteration, you may want to stop it after a certain number of cycles through the loop, so that you are not sending the user an infinite stream of data.

If you are doing something such as a calculation, you should look into using JavaScript, and making AJAX calls to the php scripts.

Comment: I just want something like batch script which gives response even it is in while loop. If I run it through curl - it's not working.